# How should I read and parse (real, proper, full-featured) CSVs in C++?

Tags: c++, csv, boost, text-parsing, boost-tokenizer

I've read:

[How can I read and parse CSV files in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1120140/1593077)

but the title there is rather misleading. It's not asking about reading CSVs per se, just multi-line comma-delimited no-escaped-data files.

Now, I want to parse *actual* CSVs - the proper format ([RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)-compliant) - with quoted fields and with line breaks, commas and double-quotes within quoted fields; and with at least the option of expecting CRLF as a record delimiter rather than LF.

To be more specific: Can I extend the boost-tokenizer-based suggestions from the simpler version of the question to handle quoting (and the other issues) properly?

Comment: Wasn't that [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1122720/1413395) in that question you mention as well?

Comment: ... and if not, parsing CSV files does not appear to be rocket science. If the existing libraries don't handle it fully to your satisfaction, then writing a CSV parser should take half a day, at a most.

Comment: Agree.  Why not just grab a CSV parsing library?

Comment: boost::spirit is appropriate

Comment: @RichardHodges and you can just scan my answers for at least 3 different takes on it, with various degrees of feature completeness (including _ridiculously complete_)

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly consider using a preexisting library.  The first one I found on google that looked reasonable was [librfc4180csv](https://github.com/gsauthof/librfc4180csv).

Comment: Can you see something about its merits? I assume it does conform to RFC 4180, but - is it reasonably speedy? It's not very standard-library-like from the looks of it. Also, does it not require the 'ragel' tool?